# What is this mans name?

Tags: riddle

Riddle:

> I met an old man on London bridge,
>   As the sun set on the ridge,
>   He tipped his hat and drew his name,
>   And cheated at the guessing game.
>
> What was the man’s name?

[Attribution pending]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Andrew. A new age Andrew, because he spells it Anddrew.